# Present Full-Screen UIViewController @iOS13

Tags: swift, xcode11, ios13

I am currently trying out the iOS 13 SDK and trying to present a new view out of my code from another view.

Before iOS 13 I always used:

```
self.present(self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! UIViewController, animated: true)
```

for it.

It is still working and the view is shown, but it is shown as Modal which can be dismissed by the user, what should not be possible.

I already tried to use self.show() and the modalPresentationStyle property, but the result is always the same (See image).
[image: My login view presented as modal...]